# Filter a 2d array to keep rows with a value in any column which case-insensitively matches a search substring

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, case-insensitive, array-filter

I have a script which allows me to filter an entire multidimensional array according to a string.
But it will only work if a value of the array matches the string exactly while I would like it to work when the string is at least contained in the value.

So, in other words, if the string is "nana", I would like the filtering to let the values "Banana" and "Ananas" be a match.
So I would like the search to be done on "%nana%" in order to allow any combination of letters before and after the "nana" string.

Here is my code so far:

```
$dataset = [
    [3, "Yellow", "Banana"],
    [2, "Brown", "Ananas"],
    [1, "Green", "brown"]
];

$dataset = array_filter($dataset, function ($v){
    return filterArray('anana', $v);
});

function filterArray($needle,$haystack){
    $needle = strtolower($needle);

    foreach($haystack as $k => $v){
        $haystack[$k] = strtolower($v);
    };
   
    return in_array($needle,$haystack);
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($dataset); echo '</pre>';
```

This won't work.

I made my homework and found that "fnmatch" or "preg_match" are referenced rather often for this case. The problem is I don't see where they should be in my script. The cases I've browsed are different enough for me not to know how to use them properly here.
So it's not about looking the proper function per se but rather about understanding how and where to use it.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
....
foreach($haystack as $k => $v){
    if(preg_match('/^'.$needle.'$/i', $v)) {    
        $haystack[$k] = strtolower($v);
    } 
};
....
```

And this didn't work neither:

```
....
foreach($haystack as $k => $v){
    if(preg_match("/\b$needle\b/i", $v)) {
        $haystack[$k] = strtolower($v); 
    } 
};
....
```

I also tried this :

```
....
$dataset = array_filter(dataset, function ($v){
    return filter((bool)preg_match("/$needle/i",$v);
});
....
```

None of those changes did any good and it feels to me like I exhausted the solutions found online and in here about this.

I also tried to use "fnmatch", even if I wasn't sure how and where to use it, but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to do a case-insensitive search for the `$needle` anywhere inside the `$haystack` value:

```
$dataset=[[3,"Yellow","Banana"], [2,"Brown","Ananas"], [1,"Green","brown"]];

$dataset = array_filter($dataset, function ($v){
    return filterArray('anana', $v);
});

function filterArray($needle,$haystack){
    foreach($haystack as $v){
        if (stripos($v, $needle) !== false) return true;
    };
    return false;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($dataset); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Yellow
            [2] => Banana
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Brown
            [2] => Ananas
        )
)
</pre>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cNARN)

Comment: Nice, thank you ! I've seen this function too when I did my research but it seemed to be the most esoteric way to make it work considering my lack of knowledge. It wasn't clear where the stripos function should be in my script. Thank you very much.
One bonus question if you don't mind: how come, with that function, that I don't have to compare my string against the lowered case values of the array as I did ($haystack[$k] = strtolower($v);). Is "stripos" always case insensitive by default?
Thanks!

Comment: @BachirMessaouri no worries. To answer the bonus question, yes, `stripos` is *always* case-insensitive for both *needle* and *haystack* (indicated by the `i` in the name compared to `strpos`)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to check if a string contains another string.

```
function filterArray($needle,$haystack){

    foreach($haystack as $k => $v){

        if (stripos($v, $needle) !== false) return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much ! Nick already gave me the same answer that I accepted but of course, yours is just as good. Thanks.